# How to run every instance of for loop after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

How to run every instance of for loop after 5 seconds?

I tried the following code but it didn't work

```
setTimeout(function(){
    for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        alert("Okay user"+i);
    }
},3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("Okay user"+i);
    }, i * 5000)
}
```

Comment: Nope, this code doesn't work. Every instance of the loop runs after 5 seconds but on every instance of the loop the alert function prints the last element 15. I want the alert function to print the current value of i.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function myLoop(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hello user'+i);             
   if (i++ < (15 - 1)) myLoop(i);  
  }, 3000)
})(0);
```